# C# new without reference holder?

Tags: c#, reference, stack

When writing

`Console.Write(new Class().Work)`

Does ‘new class` still generates a reference ?

What will be the value on the stack ? (address)

Comment: Yes, when you call new ClassName() , it returns a reference, even if you don't assign it to anything, and even if it somehow optimize it to not actually return the reference, Work still might access a local member, or require referencial information

Comment: The "value on the stack" is an implementation detail.  IOW you don't need to know that.  If you really want to know what happens under the covers, examine the IL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is: newobj, callvirt, call

Yes, an object is created - the reference is on the stack, and is consumed by the callvirt (leaving the return value of the method for call)

No variable is required, although it would be just as legal with one.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it generates a reference, an instance of `Class` has to exist in order to call `Work` on it. There just isn't a variable to hold it.

Not sure what you mean about the stack.

Comment: The stack holds the address value

Comment: @RoyiNamir sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean here.

Answer (score 1):

It is going be on the reference. The new class in your question. The value will be a HEX value on the stack address where it is pointing to the class. So in .NET if you are referencing through a reference the address is stored in a stack so that when you want to access it, the compiler finds out which HEX value and then fetch out the proper object (class, function, anything) from the heap.

Comment: Saying it is a "hex" value is misleading - the number is just an integer. Hex is just a convenient way of displaying addresses for developers - in part because they are convenient to break into pieces for typing and reading. Computers don't think in "hex" as such